# How to convert string to XPATH in BaseX

Tags: xquery, basex, xquery-3.0

How can i convert string into XPATH, below is the code

```
let $ti := "item/title"
let $tiValue :=  "Welcome to America"
return db:open('test')/*[ $tiValue = $ti]/base-uri()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to solve it:

```
let $ti := "item/title"
let $tiValue :=  "Welcome to America"

let $input := db:open('test')
let $steps := tokenize($ti, '/')
let $process-step := function($input, $step) { $input/*[name() = $step] }
let $output := fold-left($input, $steps, $process-step)
let $test := $output[. = $tiValue]
return $test/base-uri()
```

The path string is split into single steps (`item`, `title`). With `fold-left`, all child nodes of the current input (initially `db:open('test')`) will be matched against the current step (initially, `item`). The result will be used as new input and matched against the next step (`title`), and so on. Finally, only those nodes with `$tiValue` as text value will be returned.

Comment: This assumes of course that the path expression is a sequence of simple child steps. We can only guess.

Comment: Nice approach (for simple steps).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very unclear - the basic problem is that you've shown us some code that doesn't do what you want, and you're asking us to work out what you want by guessing what was going on in your head when you wrote the incorrect code.

I suspect -- I may be wrong -- that you were hoping this might somehow give you the result of

```
db:open('test')/*[item/title = $ti]/base-uri()
```

and presumably $ti might hold different path expressions on different occasions.

XQuery 3.0/3.1 doesn't have any standard way to evaluate an XPath expression supplied dynamically as a string (unless you count the rather devious approach of using `fn:transform()` to invoke an XSLT transformation that uses the `xsl:evaluate` instruction).

BaseX however has an `query:eval()` function that will do the job for you. See https://docs.basex.org/wiki/XQuery_Module